# Installing Ubuntu 12.10 as primary OS?

Tags: system-installation

I have an old computer which currently runs Windows XP. I want to give Ubuntu (v12.10) a try since I heard that it requires less RAM than XP to operate. Here are its specs:

```
OS: Windows XP
RAM: 1GB
HDD: 40GB
GRAPHICS: ATI Radeon 7000 64MB
PROCESSOR: Intel Pentium IV 2.0 Ghz
```

Can someone give me advice on how to install Ubuntu? I wish to install it on the entire disk with no partitions whatsoever and to permanently delete Windows XP.

Are the specs of my PC enough to smoothly run Ubuntu and at the same time do some basic tasks (document editing, internet browsing, music, videos and some old games)?

Will Ubuntu have the drivers for my hardware?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend testing first, before getting rid of XP. Xubuntu would probably be a better distro for something that old.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you run and use the Demo version first before completely removing your XP. Select "Try" from the image below

[image: Selecting type to install]

If it all goes well and you are satisfy with the result that you get. Install Ubuntu by selecting "Replace Window 7 with Ubuntu" where in your case, Window 7 will be Window XP.

For more information, visit [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest)

[image: Installation type]

As for graphics driver, I recommend you visit this [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) on how to update/upgrade your driver to latest. Read it carefully as yours could be under the legacy drivers category. Don't just copy and paste the command line as some packages will be under a different name.

To check if Ubuntu support your video card. Visit [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware)

Comment: Additionally I suggest visiting your PC manufacturer's web site to determine if a BIOS update is available, and also update other hardware drivers - there will be a better chance for a successful Ubuntu trial and install

Answer (score 0):

i run 12.04 on my 1.5Ghz atom netbook with 1.5Gb ram. It works fine.
Basics are pretty smooth but games dont work and some software like Steam are a little laggish..) but i think your system could make it better :) give it a try anyway.
I made it this way: 2GB swap, 10GB /, 28GB /home.

Comment: I have an old Dell LapTop Intel Celeron 1.5Ghz; 2 Gb ram; 40 Gb HDD and am running 12.10 - I used session fall back because Unity was too resource intensive. I would suggest that you "try Ubuntu" for a week or so using either Live CD or bootable pen drive - if your pc will boot from USB that will be a faster boot solution. Try it fully and after you're satisfied all your hardware is functioning then you can replace WinXP and let then installer arrange the partitions